# Batch file quitting after doing "call :loop"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bit of (Bad) Code for encrypting text, but to be able to decrypt it needs to have something inbetween the numbers. I want to fit random letters inbetween the numbers so it looks less obvious, this is where i got to:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion


set /p code=Text:
set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz


for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Set _count=0
set _RNDLen=%random%
Set /A _RNDLen=_RNDLen%%4
If !_count! leq %_RNDLen% call :loop


set "code=!code:%%C=-%%N!"

)

)

echo !code!
echo !_str!
pause

:loop
Set /a _count+=1
set _RND=%random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%51
SET _str=!_str!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The problem is that the program just quits before giving any output, even if i remove the exit /b statement. Thanks for help

Comment: Odd that you are using delayed expansion for some variables but not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what principle you're using for your algorithm, but fundamentally you need to understand `delayed expansion`.

When your outer loop, `for %%N` is parsed, every `%var%` is replaced by the contents of that variable *at that time*, hence

```
set _RNDLen=%random%

If !_count! leq %_RNDLen% call :loop
```

are replaed by

```
set _RNDLen=a specific random number

If !_count! leq call :loop
```

The first line here will set `_rndlen` to the *same* number every time (for ny run) and since `_rndlen` is undefined at the start of the loop, it willl be replaced by *nothing*, hence the `if` statement has faulty syntax and hence `cmd` objects and would display a message.

You can use `!random!` with `delayed expansion` invoked to select a rendom number *each time*, and you need `!_rndlen!` to access the *changed* value of `_rndlen` (changed from its original value of *nothing* to some random value and then mod-4'd)

Personally, I'd assign `_alphanumeric` *outside* of the (outer) loop since its value isn't varied by the loop operation.

And naturally, you know that when you hit <kbd>Return</kbd> following the `pause`, the `loop` code will be executed before the routine terminates (by flow-through) and you should include a

```
goto :eof
```

line after the `pause` to skip this last operation.